# How can I earn these types of badges?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

I enjoy earning badges and collecting reputation on this site, but as I browsed the profile of some of the more veteran users, I saw a type of badge like this:

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the [enter tag] tag.

How exactly can I go about obtaining these types of badges?

Comment: Give lots of good, non-wiki answers for a specific tag?

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail please?

Comment: Best bet would be to find a tag that is fairly popular (enough questions for you to answer) that you can make good answers on (get the upvotes).  Then just keep paying attention to that tag and you'll eventually get it.

Comment: @Batophobia *cough cough cough [tag:minecraft] cough cough*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence is fairly self-explanatory, but here's some more expanded detail.

Within the tag in question, you must have posted at least 20 answers that were not marked as community wiki. Across all of those answers, you need to have accumulated 100 total upvotes.

If you get 100 upvotes on 15 answers, that won't meet the criteria. If you get 75 upvotes on 30 answers, that also won't meet the criteria. You need to meet both numbers.

Comment: I am understanding the part of aquiring lots of votes on specific number of questions, but does it mean any question (as long as they all share the game tag)? Example: Could I go and answer (get accepted) 30 TF2 Questions and get a total of 150 rep to earn the badge?

Comment: @ShadowZ. This works for any tag. So you could answer 20+ [tag:team-fortress-2] questions to get the Team Fortress 2 version of the tag. You need 100 *upvotes*, however, not 100 *reputation*. This would amount to 1000 reputation.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarifcation. I kept confusing my when I read it. (I see I messed up on the reputation part).